# Crypt Field encryption error PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, opayo

I am trying to send Crypt data to sagepay test website from my php form.
I am using saegepay 2.23 php kit to  Crypt data using the function encryptAndEncode().

When i am passing the data i am getting the error 
Status: INVALID

Status Detail:  3003 : The Currency is invalid.

my code is as follows

> include "library.php";
>
> $CRYPT =  "VendorTxCode=56g9 &Amount=320 &Currency=GBP
>   &Description=Ticket &SuccessURL=EDITED-OUT/registered-thanks
>   &FailureURL=EDITED-OUT/registered-fail &BillingSurname=aaqib
>   &BillingFirstnames=Abc &BillingAddress1=abc &BillingCity=London
>   &BillingPostCode=se1234 &BillingCountry=UK &DeliverySurname=zar
>   &DeliveryFirstnames= &DeliverAddress1= &DeliveryCity=
>   &DeliveryPostCode= &DeliveryCountry=UK &AllowGiftAid=1";
>
> $strCrypt = encryptAndEncode($CRYPT);
>
> ?>

```
form
 action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp"
 method="POST" id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">
     <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="2.23" />
     <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT" />
     <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="myvendorkey" />
     <input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<?= $strCrypt  ?>">    
     <input type="image" src="http://ebizmarts.com/addons/shared_addons/themes/baseebizmarts/img/logos/sagepay_logo_main-250.gif"
 /> </form>
```

In library file i am assigning $strEncryptionPassword  to my encyption key provided by sagepay.

Thank you

Comment: I am not familiar with saegepay, however many encryption/decryption functions use **php-mcrypt**. Which is a server-side php module.  The installation can be found here --> http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php

Comment: Maybe that site doesn't accept GBP Currency, try with USD... I had this problem once with EUR.

Comment: There are spaces in your values which will cause the crypt to be incorrect if Sage Pay are not trimming whitespace in values.

Answer (score 0):

Please triple check that the encryption password is correct, the error message might seem misleading but generally the error is because of a wrong encryption password.

Regards,

Pablo

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have spaces on the end of all of your fields, so the currency is being sent as `GBP` (four characters, including the space). Remove the spaces.